# Comparar o Array do explode com texto do select option

Tags: php

Como comparar o `Array` do `explode`, com o **texto** do `option`. Caso seja igual, marcar com **selected**.

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include 'config.php';

$rs2 = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE id_subcategoria = '{$_GET['id']}' AND idioma = 'pt-br' ");

$rs3 = $conexao->query("SELECT habilidades FROM categoriasub WHERE ID_Subcategoria = '{$_GET['id']}' AND idioma = 'pt-br' ");
$row3 = $rs3->fetch_assoc();


$habilidades = explode(",", $row3['habilidades']);



while($row2 = $rs2->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row2['ID_Tag'].'">'.$row2['tag'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

**Resultado do while**

```
<option value="1">PHP</option> 
<option value="2">MYSQL</option>
<option value="3">HTML</option>
<option value="4">Designer de site</option>
```

**Resultado do Array $habilidades**

```
Array
(
    [0] => PHP
    [1] =>  HTML
    [2] =>  Designer de site
)
```

Comment: Neste caso seriam 3 opções selecionadas? Você está utilizando `multiple` no `select` do HTML?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Exatamente. Sim estou usando o `multiple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare o valor que vem do banco com o array de habilidades com a função `in_array()` caso encontre atribuia `$selected` o valor de selecionado. Depois monte o template com `printf()`.

```
while($row2 = $rs2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $selected = in_array($row2['tag'],$habilidades) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; 
    printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', $row2['ID_Tag'], $selected, $row2['tag']);
}
```

Comment: Retornou assim `<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option><option value="2" >2</option><option value="3" >3</option><option value="4" >4</option>`

Comment: @Tiago Corrigi o código, o tinha coloado duas vezes o `$row2['ID_Tag']`. Agora deve funcionar como o esperado.

Comment: Estava respondendo com um exemplo, mas como é a mesma solução, fica o link: http://ideone.com/n7fLP2

Comment: Só esta selecionando o primeiro.  <option value="1" selected="selected">PHP</option><option value="2" >MYSQL</option><option value="3" >HTML</option><option value="4" >Designer de site</option>``

Comment: @Tiago verifique se há espaços em branco no campo de habilidades. Se existir, deve removê-los com a função `trim`.

Comment: Acessei o link, la ele funciona certo, no meu codigo só seleciona o primeiro

Comment: Vou fazer isso agora.

Comment: @Tiago além do `trim()` comentando o texto usa a mesma caixa ou tudo minuscula ou tudo maiuscula?

Comment: @rray Tem que ser padronizado caixa alta ou baixa?

Comment: @Tiago sim, se não  a comparação não sai certa.

Comment: @rray Esse link que o Anderson fez funciona http://ideone.com/n7fLP2

Comment: @Tiago suas habilidades estão escritas como?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Já tentei usar o `trim` e mesmo assim aqui não vai.

Comment: @Tiago tem como mostrar o código?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, é espaço mesmo, fiz um teste tirando eles do BD, pois são separados por virgura e um espaços para inciar outro. Certamente como estou fazendo deve estar errado. `$habilidades = explode(",", trim($row3['habilidades']));


while($row2 = $rs2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $selected = in_array(trim($row2['tag']), $habilidades) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', $row2['ID_Tag'], $selected, trim($row2['tag']));
}
?>`

Comment: @Tiago faça assim, http://ideone.com/UM4uNq, que os espaços serão removidos. Só tome o devido cuidado com a caixa do texto, como o rray citou. Você pode usar as funções `strtoupper` ou `strtolower` para evitar problemas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Show de bola, agora funcionou :D